# Number of point subsets defined by a polygon

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

If $S$ is set of $n$ points in the plane, then $S$ has $2^n$ different subsets. We say that a subset $T\subseteq S$ is "defined by a polygon" if there is a polygon which has $T$ in its interior and $S\setminus T$ in its exterior.

For every $n$, define $F(n)$ as the maximum number of subsets defined by a polygon (maximum over all subsets of $n$ points).

What is an asymptotic bound on $F(n)$ when the defining polygon is:

- A square?
- A rectangle?
- A convex polygon with $d$ sides?
- Any convex polygon?

Is there a general reference for solving such problems?

Comment: This depends a lot on the distribution of $S$. If all points actually lie on a line, all convex shapes can produce only $n+1\choose 2$ subsets.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks. I added that I am looking for an upper bound (maximized over all subsets of $n$ points).